# Why does my external resource not work in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I have created a simple [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dirkjf/collapsible) for collapsible elements with an option to close the element when clicked outside of it with an attribute `data-close-on-click-outside`. Locally it works, and also if I were to copy the JS into JSFiddle it works, but when I include the JS from a CDN, the event listener does not seem to be triggered. An example can be seen in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dirkjf/3uds5fxe/). **Why does my code not work when included as a resource from a CDN in JSFiddle?**

n.b.: I do not think there is something wrong with my code, as it works everywhere except on JSFiddle (minified or not), but for completeness here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<button data-collapsible-target="collapsible-close">Toggle me</button>
<div class="collapsible-close" data-close-on-click-outside>
    This *should* close when clicked outside...
</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

  const element = event.target;
  const targetSelector = element.getAttribute('data-collapsible-target');

  if (targetSelector !== null) {
    toggleCollapse(targetSelector);
  }
}, false);

const toggleCollapse = targetSelector => {
  const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.' + targetSelector);
  targets.forEach(target => {
    if (!target.classList.contains('collapsible-show')) {
      target.style.maxHeight = target.scrollHeight + 'px';
    } else {
      target.style.maxHeight = 0 + 'px';
    }
    target.classList.toggle('collapsible-show');
  });
}

const closeOnClickOutsideElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-on-click-outside]');
closeOnClickOutsideElements.forEach(element => hideOnClickOutside(element))

function hideOnClickOutside(element) {
  const outsideClickListener = event => {
    // Third checks if the element clicked isn't the toggler, which would result in a double click event that conflict each other.
    if (!element.contains(event.target) && isVisible(element) && !element.classList.contains(event.target.getAttribute('data-collapsible-target'))) {
      element.classList.remove('collapsible-show')
      element.style.maxHeight = 0;
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener('click', outsideClickListener)
  const isVisible = elem => !!elem && !!(elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight || elem.getClientRects().length) // source (2018-03-11): https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/hiddenVisibleSelectors.js
}
```

**Edit:** figured it out, see answer below.

Comment: Do you get any CORS errors?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, no CORS errors. The script is also loaded (toggling works), just the event listener does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle loads the resource in the `<head>` of the file. This resource works if it is added at the end of the `<body>`, before the closing tag `</body>`. I could change the script by wrapping it in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {});` if I wanted to be able to use in when it is included in the `<head>` of the document.